# Go to implementation - set default

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio always had this nice `Go to Definition` command that takes you to the definition of a method. But in case cursor is on an interface member and there are multiple interface implementations, it lists all implementations in a tool window instead (you can then cruise through that list and press Enter to select the implementation that you want to go to).

Is there a way in Visual Studio to mark one implementation as *default*, so to speak, so that choosing `Go to Definition` would take us directly to that implementation instead of showing the list of all implementations?

### Background

The interface `IDataService` has got two implementations; `DesignerDataService` for the designer that returns static data (doesn't contact server to save time) and `RealDataService` that does the real thing. I almost always need to go to `RealDataService` when I choose `Go to Definition`, so it would be nice if I could tell Visual Studio about it.

Comment: The more I think about this, the less it makes sense as a feature. For example, what if you change your mind, you obviously need a way to revert to the original behavior and/or select another "default" implementation. You wouldn't want to go digging into the solution config and change it manually, right? What if you implement the interface in a new class? Should VS still remember the selected one or should it re-ask you?

Comment: @41686d6564: MVVM Light handles a similar (well, not so similar) situation using .NET attributes. When your VM class contains multiple constructors, MVVM Light needs you to mark one of them as *preferred constructor*, by applying `[PreferredConstructor]` attribute on it. Something similar could be done, but at class level, e.g. `[DefaultImplementation(IDataService)]`. Just thinking loudly.

Answer (score 0):

I would just temporarily unload the project containing DesignerDataService when debugging.

Comment: They both live in the same project and same namespace.